# Salesforce Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs: for processing jobs progress is not showing up

Tags: api, salesforce

We are not able to see the progress while Salesforce job(bulk-api) is being processing. Now We're exporting 300.000 tasks and the job is there for 4 days, however we can not see any progress on it. Is there a way we can see the progress? We need to know when it's going to be finished.

[image: Salesforce processing state]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A job by itself doesn't do any work. It is batches that are queued to jobs that actually carry on data modifications. An open job will stay open until closed or until timed out (after 1 week if I remember correctly). The open status therefore does not signify progress, it only means you can queue more batches to this job.

As you can see on your second screenshot, no batches were queued to this job. Check the code that actually queues the batches, the API probably returns some kind of error there.